# How to change existing column type of a table in Sybase?

Tags: sybase, alter-table

I searched for a while and can't get an answer.

Why this doesn't work?
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN price DOUBLE

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does it do the wrong thing? Does it give you an error? What error?

Comment: The sql query you have mentioned is syntactically wrong !
You shall `MODIFY` the column.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect and there is no DOUBLE datatype in Sybase.

So, you may try it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY price float
```

Answer (score 1):

To alter any table in order to change the datatype of some field :
`ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> <new_datatype>`
For example:
In order to change the datatype of any column 'emp_id' from *int* to *varchar*, you need to :
`ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY emp_id varchar(10)`
Isn't it simple ?